# Por que dividir por 4 o valor do potenciometro?

Tags: arduino

```
int ledPin = 13; // pino do led
```

int analogPin = 3; // pino para leitura do potenciômetro

int val = 0; //variável para armazenar o valor lido

void setup()

{

pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // configura pino como saída

}

void loop()

{

val = analogRead(analogPin); // le o valor analógico

**analogWrite(ledPin, val / 4); // aciona led com o valor analógico lido divido por 4**

}

Comment: Qual a versão do Arduino você está usando? Uno, Due, Mega, Mini?

Comment: Estou usando o UNO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boas,
A resolução de saída do arduino é de 8 bits (2^8=256), a resolução de entrada é de 10 bits (2^10=1024). Se o potenciometro estiver no valor máximo, ou seja, nos 5V o valor que o arduino lê é 1023 (porque começa em zero) e como a resolução de saída é de menos 2 bits o valor máximo de saída tem que ser 255 (1023/4=255) que equivale também a 5V.

Comment: Agora eu entendi o motivo de usar o valor 4. Veja se eu estou correto. Como a saída tem o valor máximo 255. Eu uso o valor 4 para forçar que minha saída trabalhe dentro do valor limite recomendado, ou seja, pegando 1023/4 terei um inteiro de 255 valor como você mesmo disse é o máximo que essa saída poderá ter. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: exatamente, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Essa divisão é apenas para limitar o valor passado, veja abaixo:

```
val = analogRead(analogPin);  // lê o pino de entrada analógica
analogWrite(ledPin, val / 4);
```

**analogRead** retorna valores de 0 a 1023

**analogWrite** recebe de 0 a 255 por isso a divisão por 4

Para mais informações sobre fica o link para a documentação do [analogWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/pt/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, muito obrigado mesmo.